# Question on Reference Style with apacite (APA style) for User's Guide

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, apa-style, documentation, apacite

I am trying to make reference using APA style (apacite) with bibtex.
The User guide that I want to add on is not computational software manual. It is manual for flow sensor.
So I wanna take out [Computational software manual] in the reference list.
But, I dont know how to take it out.
Is there any method to edit or remove it?

Here is reference file.

```
@manual{flowmeter,
author = {{OMEGA Engineering}},
title = {User's {G}uide for {FLR}1000/1000{BR}/1000{ST} {S}eries {F}low 
{S}ensors \& {M}eters For {L}iquids},
year={2005},
organization={OMEGA Engineering inc.},
url={https://assets.omega.com/manuals/M4574.pdf}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For entries of type `@manual`, the `apacite` citation management package and associated bibliography style let you specify an extra field called `type`. If the `type` field is not specified explicitly, it's default value is (as you've found out) "Computer software manual". If you want to show just "Manual" (in square brackets), you add the field

```
type={Manual},
```

to the entry. See p. 30 of the user guide of the `apacite` package for more information.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@manual{flowmeter,
author = {{OMEGA Engineering}},
title  = {{User's Guide for FLR1000\slash 1000BR\slash 
           1000ST Series Flow Sensors \& Meters for 
           Liquids}},
year   = {2005},
organization={OMEGA Engineering inc.},
url    = {https://assets.omega.com/manuals/M4574.pdf},
type   = {Manual},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{flowmeter}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more thing: I you want to suppress the type of the manual entirely, just change the entry type from `@manual` to `@misc` (and, of course, don't specify a `type` field).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It works well. By the way, any specific reason to suppress the type of the manual?

Comment: @JeYoungKim - The extra suggestion was meant to address your objective, "So I wanna take out [Computational software manual] in the reference list". It's not my business to second-guess your reasons.